# Delay using 'Handler' not Working in Android For Loop

Tags: java, android, handler

I have a HashMap object with some values in it. I wanted to loop through these values after 3 seconds and show each value on a textView. I'm using a Handler for delay. Here is my code:

```
handler = new Handler();

for (String i: myHashmap.values()){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(null);
            textView.setText(i);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

The problem is that the above code changes the value only one time. After that, the text view is stuck on the first value of Hashmap.

Comment: did u try to use sleep();?

Comment: Use runOnUiThread to modify values on textView, I.e. `runOnUiThread { textView.setText(i); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
int count = 0;

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        textView.setText(null);
        textView.setText(myHashmap.get(count));
        if (count++ < myHashmap.size()) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    }
};

// Call first time
handler.post(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to multiply the delay and change values with a 3 seconds interval

```
int counter = 1;

for (String i : myHashmap.values()) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(i);
        }
    }, 3000 * counter);
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int i = 0;

    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("Key1", "One");
    hashMap.put("Key2", "Two");
    hashMap.put("Key3", "Three");
    hashMap.put("Key4", "Four");
    hashMap.put("Key5", "Five");

    Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(hashMap); // Sort HashMap by Key

    textView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

            if (i < strings.size())
            {
                textView.setText(strings.get(i));
                i++;
                textView.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
```